# Prevent debugging chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-app

I created a "packaged app" for Chrome browser and I do not want others to debug the app.

Is there a flag in the manifest or any other way to prevent debugging?

Comment: No, you cannot prevent devtools access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use native client and don't use any HTML/JS/DOM, except for loading the native client module, then you would not be able to debug very much with devtools.